# Basic question about typescript annotation and node packages

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript-typings

I'm new to typescript and understand the basics of it. But I'm getting a bit confused about best practices when it comes to node packages, annotations and describing the types of these when using packages in my project.

I mean, is it really needed to describe a package's return annotations, or specify data type in their parameters which are used by the packages when they are already defined with the @type downloaded?

Lets take an example of the mysql2 package.

`

```
const poolFunction = async (SQL: string): Promise < [RowDataPacket[] | RowDataPacket[][] | OkPacket | OkPacket[] | ResultSetHeader, FieldPacket[]] > => {
    return await pool.query(SQL);
}
```

`

Or express...

`

```
const routeFunction = (req: Request, res: Response): void => {
}
```

`

Of course it's very descriptive, but is it needed?

Just trying to understand and hopefully typescript in the future!

Comment: Yes - it's not only you that needs types for things.

Answer (score 0):

> is it really needed to describe a package's return annotations, or specify data type in their parameters which are used by the packages when they are already defined with the @type downloaded?

In your examples yes, because TypeScript can't know if `routeFunction` is going to be used with some Express function. By isolating it you must type the parameters, although the return type can be inferred.

TypeScript will infer the types of the parameters if you send the *expected function*, for example:

```
// no need to type app because TS already knows
// the return type of express()
const app = express();

// no need to type request or response because TS already knows
// that .get() expects a function of 2 parameters, a Request and a Response
app.get('', (request, response) => {});

// since routeFunction is declared outside an Express context,
// TS can't know that request: Request and response: Response,
// this function can be used anywhere not only for Express
function routeFunction(request, response) {} // error
```